# Kendo UI Grid Column Template

Tags: templates, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Classes having one or more students. I wanted to display multiple classes in rows and student names in that particular class as comma separated values. I have used following code but it doesn't work. It is giving runtime error as

CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

```
`columns.Bound(c => c.Students).Template               
              ( m =>                   
                 @<text> 
                    @foreach (var student in m.Students)
                     {
                        <li> @{ @student.Name; }</li>
                     }
                 </text>

        );`
```

Comment: Can you please post the grid mark-up as you are probably using Ajax() in your datasource which would make a grid to use clientTemplate. otherwise  if you are using server() operation method in your datasource then you can use ServerTemplate or simply template in case of server side binding..

Answer (score 5):

The right syntax is this:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.Students).Template(@<text> 
        <ul>
           @foreach (var student in item.Students)
           {
              <li>@student.Name</li>
           }
        </ul>
</text>);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 <li> @{ @item.student.Name; }</li>
```

instead of

```
<li> @{ @student.Name; }</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the comma-separated values in the column, I did this:

```
columns.Bound(s => s.Students).Title("Students").Template(@<text>
        @String.Join(",", (from g in item.Students select g.name))
    </text>
);
```